# Threads in a multiple cores computer

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

We observe a computer with multiple cores. In a given computer, on one core there is a running thread and on other core there is another thread running.
Is it possible that one thread belongs to the user program that is managed by an operating system and the other thread belongs to the same user program that is managed by the user?

In my opinion no because each core operates independently and executes instructions in parallel. Therefore, if a user program runs on a particular core, all threads of that program will also run on that core, and not on another core belonging to the operating system.

Comment: You might want to review the definition of a thread. Threads run concurrently and not sequentially with there parent process, except when synchronization is forced through use of a mutex or lock. Concurrent behaviors can therefore be performed on separate cores.

Comment: If it was true that all the threads in a user program were required to run together on the same core, then no program would ever be able to get a speedup by implementing multithreading, since each of the N threads it spawned would run at 1/N speed on that core.

However, we know that many user programs *do* successfully implement multithreading to obtain a processing speedup (it's one of the major reasons why people bother implementing multithreading in their programs), so we can infer that that hypothesis is incorrect.